# Selecting a shape in Office.js

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

Is there any way to select a shape in Office.js? The Excel.Shape class doesn't have a select() method like the Excel.Range class does. Is this not supported yet in Office.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such api yet to support shape.select() or shape.active() until now.We track Office Add-in feature requests on our [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions). Please add your request there. Feature requests are considered when we go through our planning process.